# Generating models from a car type simulation in SAS?

Tags: model, statistics, sas, simulation

I'm running a simulation to forecast a car dealer's inventory. The dealer sells zero cars 10% of the time, one car 50%, two cars 30% and three cars 10%. Of these cars sold, 50% are sedans, 30% are SUVs, and 20% are trucks. Additionally, the models of the cars sold are as follows:

- Sedan: 30% are 'S', 40% are 'SE', and 30% are 'SEL'
- SUV: 25% are 'S', 35% are 'SE', and 40% are 'SEL'
- Truck: 50% are 'S', 30% are 'SE', and 20% are 'SEL'

I'm trying to generate these last model distributions, but my code prints 'S' for all the days. Can you guys offer any advice? Thanks!

[image: SAS code]

Here's the code in text:

```
data cars (drop=perc_sales car_type_perc subtype_perc);
format date date9.;
    date='01Jan2016'd;
    do until (date > '31Dec2016'd);
        if 
            weekday(date) not in (1)
            and date not in ('01Jan2016'd,'04Jul2016'd,'25Dec2016'd)
            then output;
        date=intnx('day',date,1);
    S_price1 = 15000+200*rand('normal');    *Sedan;
    S_price2 = 30000+500*rand('normal');    *SUV;
    S_price3 = 25000+300*rand('normal');    *Truck;
    perc_sales = rand('uniform');
    car_type_perc = rand('uniform');
    subtype_perc = rand('uniform');
        if 0 < perc_sales <= 0.1 then Ncars = 0;                * 10% chance zero cars sold;
        if 0.1 < perc_sales <= 0.6 then Ncars = 1;              * 50% chance one car sold;
        if 0.6 < perc_sales <= 0.9 then Ncars = 2;              * 30% chance two cars sold;
        if 0.9 < perc_sales <= 1 then Ncars = 3;                * 10% chance three cars sold;
        if 0 < car_type_perc <= 0.5 then type = 'Sedan';        * 50% of cars sold are sedans;
        if 0.5 < car_type_perc <= 0.8 then type = 'SUV';        * 30% of cars sold are SUVs;
        if 0.8 < car_type_perc <= 1 then type = 'Truck';        * 20% of cars sold are trucks;
        if type = 'Sedan' and 0 < rand('uniform') <= 0.3 then model = 'S';
        if type = 'Sedan' and 0.3 < rand('uniform') <= 0.7 then model = 'SE';
        if type = 'Sedan' and 0.7 < rand('uniform') <= 1 then model = 'SEL';
        if type = 'SUV' and 0 < rand('uniform') <= 0.25 then model = 'S';
        if type = 'SUV' and 0.25 < rand('uniform') <= 0.6 then model = 'SE';
        if type = 'SUV' and 0.6 < rand('uniform') <= 1 then model = 'SEL';
        if type = 'Truck' and 0 < rand('uniform') <= 0.5 then model = 'S';
        if type = 'Truck' and 0.5 < rand('uniform') <= 0.8 then model = 'SE';
        if type = 'Truck' and 0.8 < rand('uniform') <= 1 then model = 'SEL';
    end;
run;
```

Comment: Code should be entered as text, not picture - I can't copy and paste a picture into my editor (well, and have it do anything useful).

Comment: Sorry about that - I didn't know I could use ctrl+k for easier pasting.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your variable `model` has a length of `$1` because the first time it is seen, it's `'S'`.  Define lengths for variables, always.

Second, you need to assign `rand('uniform')` to a variable for your `type` calculations.  The code above should sometimes not assign model, because each call is a new random number.  You do it right for `car_type_perc` and such, but not for type.  Sometimes type is not being assigned; you're doing this in one data step loop iteration, so you probably don't notice this except with the initial row sometimes, but it's not currently doing what you want it to do.

Third, why is your output at the top of the loop?  Because you exclude January 1, it doesn't really break anything, but you're outputting before you calculate anything; it's sort of odd to do it that way.  Normally you'd either add a `continue;` statement in that if block, and you'd output at the end of the loop for all other cases.

Fourth, you should add a call to `call streaminit(#)` (with whatever positive number you want there) so your sample is replicable.

Finally, I think there are better ways to do this (though the above isn't particularly bad, just a bit hard to maintain and hard to always get right).  Create a 'source' dataset with the basics of this, for example, with 1000 cars distributed nonrandomly but matching the above (that's basically every possible combination of the 3 percentages - you could do it with a bit less, but 1000 is easy).  Then `PROC SURVEYSELECT` with a with-replacement method will generate samples of whatever size you want.  Rick Wicklin has a book, Simulating Data with SAS, and some great posts on his [blog, The DO Loop](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/01/29/sample-with-replacement-in-sas/), that are probably helpful for this.

Here's some small changes to make this work properly and to make it a little simpler.  I would do this quite a bit differently, as the long set of IF statements is hard to read and maintain, but if that's what works for you, that's your choice.

Significant changes other than above:  I changed your loop to a DO loop because dates are integers and that's easier to read; added `STOP` as that's technically necessary (SAS will work around it, but you should have it); moved OUTPUT to the bottom, and added CONTINUE to the top.  Also added a CALL MISSING after the output to make sure nothing trickles into the next row.

```
data cars (drop=perc_sales car_type_perc subtype_perc);
    format date date9.;  
    length model $3 type $5;
    call streaminit(7);
    do date = '01Jan2016'd to '31Dec2016'd;
        if 
            weekday(date) = 1 or date in ('01Jan2016'd,'04Jul2016'd,'25Dec2016'd)
            then continue;
    S_price1 = 15000+200*rand('normal');    *Sedan;
    S_price2 = 30000+500*rand('normal');    *SUV;
    S_price3 = 25000+300*rand('normal');    *Truck;
    perc_sales = rand('uniform');
    car_type_perc = rand('uniform');
    subtype_perc = rand('uniform');
        if 0 < perc_sales <= 0.1 then Ncars = 0;                * 10% chance zero cars sold;
        if 0.1 < perc_sales <= 0.6 then Ncars = 1;              * 50% chance one car sold;
        if 0.6 < perc_sales <= 0.9 then Ncars = 2;              * 30% chance two cars sold;
        if 0.9 < perc_sales <= 1 then Ncars = 3;                * 10% chance three cars sold;
        if 0 < car_type_perc <= 0.5 then type = 'Sedan';        * 50% of cars sold are sedans;
        if 0.5 < car_type_perc <= 0.8 then type = 'SUV';        * 30% of cars sold are SUVs;
        if 0.8 < car_type_perc <= 1 then type = 'Truck';        * 20% of cars sold are trucks;
        if type = 'Sedan' and 0 < subtype_perc <= 0.3 then model = 'S';
        if type = 'Sedan' and 0.3 < subtype_perc <= 0.7 then model = 'SE';
        if type = 'Sedan' and 0.7 < subtype_perc <= 1 then model = 'SEL';
        if type = 'SUV' and 0 < subtype_perc <= 0.25 then model = 'S';
        if type = 'SUV' and 0.25 < subtype_perc <= 0.6 then model = 'SE';
        if type = 'SUV' and 0.6 < subtype_perc <= 1 then model = 'SEL';
        if type = 'Truck' and 0 < subtype_perc <= 0.5 then model = 'S';
        if type = 'Truck' and 0.5 < subtype_perc <= 0.8 then model = 'SE';
        if type = 'Truck' and 0.8 < subtype_perc <= 1 then model = 'SEL';
        output;
        call missing(of model type ncars);
    end;
    stop;
run;
```

Comment: I feel like I'm very close to getting it right with this code - the way I wrote it is intuitive to me, and I think it should be working. The problem comes with the nine    if type    statements.

Comment: @TimRoberson Did you fix the first two problems that I pointed out then?

Comment: Yes, after defining the length of "model," the code ran just like I had wanted. It produces the same result as what you provided. Thanks for the help! As an aside, what does the call streaminit function do?

Comment: If you don't fix the 9 if statements, it won't produce correct data - you're not always reassigning model.  `CALL STREAMINIT` sets the random number seed, so you can guarantee to get reproducible results (as long as the number is the same, you get the same exact output).